# Передать значение функции в value inputa

Tags: jquery, php, javascript

Добрый день! Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться.

Хочу в форму в value вставить значение из js.

Вот:

```
        $(".buyitem2").click(function(){    
        var na= $(this).closest(".product-table, .product-index, .product-line,   .product-indexSkroll, .catalog-detail").find("h2").text();

        $("#cart222").text(na);

        return false;
        });
```

**.buyitem2** - это класс для кнопки, по нажатию которой и передается значение (название товара), по которому кликнули:

```
<a class="buyitem2" href=""><img class="addtocard-index" src="<?=TEMPLATE?>images/zakaz-sale.jpg" alt="Нет в наличии" /></a>
```

Я вставляю следующий код в value:

```
value="<?php echo "«<strong><span style='color: #0080FF;' id='cart222'></span></strong>»"; ?>"
```

но выходит все то же самое, что написано в echo.

**Если вставлять просто в блок div код php, то название выводится отлично. :)**

***Обновление:***

```
 <form action="" method="post" id="contact2">
         <table  border="0" cellspacing="2" cellpadding="0" class="regtable">                               
                 <tr>
                     <td>
`                        `Название продукта <strong style="color:red;">*</strong>
                     </td>
                     <td>
                         <label class="net" for="email">Название продукта</label><input type="text" name="tovars" id="tovars" value="<?php echo "«<strong><span style='color: #0080FF;' id='cart222'></span></strong>»"; ?>" />
                     </td>
                 </tr>

          </table>
    </form>
```

Comment: Подскажите кто-нибудь, как обработать код.

Comment: а `value` у какого элемента? Напишите данный кусок html полностью. В принципе так нельзя делать, вставлять в  value для элемента код, он не будет обрабатываться, поэтому нужно немного поменять код

Comment: @MasterAlex, Добрый вечер, обновил код.

Answer (score 1):

Для добавления значения в `input` используйте функцию [val()](http://api.jquery.com/val/):

```
$(".buyitem2").click(function(){    
  var na = $(this).closest(".product-table, .product-index, .product-line, .product-indexSkroll, .catalog-detail").find("h2").text();

  $("#tovars").val(na);

  return false;
});
```

а для стилей текста, которые вы хотели сделать в html, добавьте в css:

```
#tovars {
  color: #0080FF;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

и из html можно смело убирать этот кусок:

```
value="<?php echo "«<strong><span style='color: #0080FF;' id='cart222'></span></strong>»"; ?>"
```